# How can I get the approximate matching records for a single column in 2 tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to get the list of approximate matching records from both the tables. Two tables are not related to each other. But, it contains common data. I wrote the query below which is not returning any result

```
SELECT 
   MemberName, 
   counterpartyname 
FROM 
   Member,
   LegalEntity 
WHERE 
   '%  MemberName%'='%counterparty%'
```

**or**

```
SELECT 
   MemberName, 
   counterpartyname 
FROM 
   Member a,
   LegalEntity b
WHERE 
   a.MemberName=b.CounterpartyName
```

is returning exact result.

I want to check approximate matches also. 
The dummy data values in both member name and counter party name is :
FIRST HAWAIIAN BANK
Bank of India
Cosmos Bank

Comment: you need [full text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use `LIKE` operation with `% _string_ %` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
where MemberName like '%' + counterparty + '%'
Or counterparty like '%' + MemberName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select both via wildcard, try something like this...

```
SELECT 
   MemberName, 
   counterpartyname 
FROM 
   Member,
   LegalEntity 
WHERE 
   MemberName LIKE '%' + counterpartyname + '%' OR
   counterpartyname LIKE '%' + MemberName + '%'
```